# MySQL Connector/C The requested metafile operation not supported when trying to connect using localhost rather than 127.0.0.1

Tags: mysql, c, windows, winsock, mysql-connector

I compiled Connector/C from scratch, and when I try to connect using it, my_connect returns -1 and WSAGetLastError() == 2003

I have no clue what's wrong, any ideas? I've tried googling but I can't even find anything on what that error means.

```
    MYSQL *my = mysql_init(NULL);
    if(my)
    {
        MYSQL *result  = mysql_real_connect(my, strHost.c_str(), strUser.c_str(), strPass.c_str(), 
            strDB.c_str(), uiPort, NULL, 0);
    }
```

Edit: Odd, when I use 127.0.0.1 to connect rather than localhost, it works.

Comment: `2003` is not a standard winsock error code. And what is `my_connect`? Do you mean `mysql_connect`?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg my_connect is an internal function of libmysql. If you're on a windows machine open cmd and type in "net helpmsg 2003" you'll get "The requested metafile operation not supported" That's what WSAGetLastError is giving.

Comment: Are you sure that `WSAGetLastError` is the correct function to call to get the error?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yes, that's sun/oracle's code, and not mine. my_connect is also just an alias for connect(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737625(v=vs.85).aspx) for x-platform reasons. Look under return value "error code can be retrieved by calling WSAGetLastError."

Comment: Then I think it's time to show some code. How do you call the function? How do you initialize everything?`Etc.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I added the relevant code to the ?, although I don't think it'll help much. I've stepped through it and verified that that values for all of those strings are indeed correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tracked the problem down to the MySQL C connector using the ipv6 getaddrinfo which returns ::1, I'm using an old mysql server version which doesn't support ipv6.